# Tapping Like button goes to page with Beta across page

Tags: ios, facebook

My iOS app (Objective-C) uses the Facebook SDK to allow users to login via Facebook. This works fine. I am also using the FBSDKLikeControl class to allow users to tap the Facebook Like button which gives them the ability to Like my community page on Facebook. When a user taps the Like button it goes to the correct community page and allows them to like it but there is a blue 'Beta' banner across the top left corner of the page. Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When one of the buttons is tapped, it will return to your app and update the state of the like button along with the like count and/or sentence, if present. The BETA banner will be present until your app has been approved to use the Native Like Button feature.

[Source.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/like-button)

Comment: I saw this on the Facebook developer site but this specifically says for SDK v.3 and it uses FBLikeControl class from the Facebook SDK framework. I am using SDK v.4 with the associated FBSDKLikeControl class from the FBSDKShareKit framework. That's what so confusing to me. This should be working without giving the Beta banner.

Comment: Actually, initially I was using SDK v.3 and was getting a blank page when the Like button was pressed, but then switched to SDK.v4. Maybe there are remnants of SDK v.3 somewhere in my code which is messing stuff up. I'll do a check.

Comment: The dialog behavior is the same regardless if you're using v3 or v4 of the SDK, so what @Zolnoor quoted above still applies.

Comment: What @MingLi said is correct. It still applies. This is most likely a feature they will leave in all versions of their SDK just so users will know their app has yet to be approved for likes. Please don't forget to mark this answer as accepted so future users will know. :)

Comment: I did submit the app to Facebook initially and they said the Like feature is a Social Plugin and therefore the app does not need permissions and did not have to be reviewed for approval. Anyway, I'll go ahead and mark this as answered. Thanks for the comments.